# Integration with Microsoft Teams using apis

Tags: azure, api, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I try to integrate with Microsoft Teams like get class, add class ...
I have access as admin to Teams, and I get tenant id and client id, but require redirect_uri. I don't know what thas mean ? I can put a http://localhost ..? and how to do this , right now I download xammp ...
I use postman to get and post api , I need a brief step and information to do this, I look to official documentation of Microsoft Teams I don't understand all think so I need a good programmer to help understand every step.
Regards

Comment: To access any protected resource like Microsoft Graph API, you need to register in Azure AD, get a token. During the app registration you need to specify the Redirect URI/reply URL; it's the location where the authorization server sends the user once the app has been successfully authorized and granted an authorization code or access token. Authorization server sends the code or token to the redirect URI, so it's important you register the correct location as part of the app registration process. Here are the [steps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

Comment: Tino, does the above helped?

Comment: Moving this to answer. Consider upvoting it and accept it answered. So it can be useful to others in the community as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access any protected resource like Microsoft Graph API, you need to register in Azure AD, get a token. During the app registration you need to specify the Redirect URI/reply URL; it's the location where the authorization server sends the user once the app has been successfully authorized and granted an authorization code or access token. Authorization server sends the code or token to the redirect URI, so it's important you register the correct location as part of the app registration process. Here are the [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reply-url).

Comment: I am getting 200 response with redirecting the HTML page as a response. even I have updated my redirect URL as http://localhost. can you guide to fix this issue.

Comment: Could you please give more information on your issue?